# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Tags: datediff

running this line of code :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

I receive the error

> Error Code: 1582
>
> Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Could you please help me solve this issue?

I use SQLyog Community - MySQL GUI v12.09

Thanks a lot,

Carlo

Comment: [RTFM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), you have 3 paramiters, it requires 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the interval with DATEDIFF.  It only returns the number of days.  Only 2 parameters are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 parameters worked for me but W3Schools shows 3 parameters and it drove me crazy. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean directly into your answer?

Comment: If you go to the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp the Syntax shows 3 parameters. 
DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)

Answer (score 1):

use
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, '201/08/25', '2017/08/25') AS DateDiff

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between the two dates:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate;
```

This returns -61 days.